# Kotlin multiplatform library not generating iosSimulatorArm64Main, iosArm64Main, iosX64Main and tests targets

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am creating a kotlin multiplatform library which has only kotlin code in `commonMain` and nothing in iOS main and androidMain,

and am using GithubPackages to distribute it, using command line `./gradlew publish` , I am publishing it to the GitHub packages but it fails to generate the asset needed for  `iosSimulatorArm64Main, iosSimulatorArm64Test, iosArm64Main, iosArm64Test, iosX64Test`, the library is working fine with android projects but not working at all with the KMM projects

my `build.gradle.kts` for the library looks like this

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    `maven-publish`
}

group = "in.getswipe"
version = "0.0.5"

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "in.getswipe"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //put your multiplatform dependencies here
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
            }
        }
    }

    publishing {

        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "GitHubPackages"
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/suraj/calculation-engine")
                credentials {
                    username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") as String?
                    password = project.findProperty("gpr.token") as String?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "get.calculation_engine"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
}
```

My `build.gradle.kts` for my KMM project looks like this

https://pastebin.com/t48Tsq6x

the error which I am getting looks like this
[image: error message]